# validation rule for 2 checkbox

Tags: validation-rule, checkbox

I need Validation Rule for 2 checkboxes. When Checkbox1 = true you can not edit Checkbox2. But I need to have option set True on both checkboxes at one time.

Comment: Validation Rules only work after the user clicks the submit button, not before. They don't affect how form fields (e.g. check boxes) are rendered. Just to make this clear.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? [Edit] your question to add that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this task, Maybe for someone it's will be helpful:

AND(
ISCHANGED( Checkbox2 ),
Checkbox1   = True,
NOT(ISCHANGED( Checkbox1 )))